# Logstash grok pattern for nginx error dosen't work for all lines

Tags: nginx, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a grok pattern for nginx error log:

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{GREEDYDATA:text}, client: %{IP:client}, server: %{GREEDYDATA:server}, request: \"(?:%{WORD:requesttype} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}))\"(, upstream: "%{GREEDYDATA:upstream}\")?, host: "%{DATA:host}\"(, referrer: \"%{GREEDYDATA:referrer}\")?
```

And I have this kind of errors

```
2022/01/17 08:23:39 [error] 8#8: *0000016 this is my error message, client: 1.2.3.4, server: my.server.name, request: "GET /my/url/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://upstream.server.name", host: "my.server.name", referrer: "https://referrer.server.name/"
2022/01/17 12:30:41 [error] 8#8: *0000016 access forbidden by rule, client: 1.2.3.4, server: my.server.name, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "my.server.name"
2022/01/17 08:23:39 [error] 8#8: *0000016 could not be resolved
```

For testing I'm using grokconstructor in appspot and my grok pattern works great for first two lines, but I can't make it works for the last line:
[image]

What pattern will work for all three lines?

Comment: Just a note, for the key-value pairs at the end of the first two lines, you should use the [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) plugin instead of doing it in grok. So store that part using grok in a temporary field, then call kv with that field, with field_split at `, ` and value_split at `:`. And use trim_value to remove the `"`.

Comment: So if you follow my suggestion in the comment above, this should work: `(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{DATA:text}(, %{GREEDYDATA:kv_value})?$` (and then you use the kv filter on `kv_value`).

Comment: If you don't, this would work: `(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{DATA:text}(, client: %{IP:client}, server: %{GREEDYDATA:server}, request: \"(?:%{WORD:requesttype} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}))\"(, upstream: "%{GREEDYDATA:upstream}\")?, host: "%{DATA:host}\"(, referrer: \"%{GREEDYDATA:referrer}\")?)?$`. In both case, don't forget the `$`, as the pattern will fail to work properly without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would work:

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{DATA:text}(, client: %{IP:client}, server: %{GREEDYDATA:server}, request: \"(?:%{WORD:requesttype} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}))\"(, upstream: "%{GREEDYDATA:upstream}\")?, host: "%{DATA:host}\"(, referrer: \"%{GREEDYDATA:referrer}\")?)?$.
```

The last part is made optional with `()?`.

Just a note, for the key-value pairs at the end of the first two lines, you should use the [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) plugin instead of doing it in grok. So store that part using the grok filter in a temporary field like this:

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME})     \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{DATA:text}(, %{GREEDYDATA:kv_value})?$
```

And then you use the kv filter on kv_value:

```
  kv {
    field_split => " ,"
    value_spliy => ": "
    trim_value => "\""
    source => "kv_value"
  }
```

In both cases, don't forget the `$` at the end of the grok pattern, as it will fail to work properly without.